# How to properly setup a docker enviroment for a new development

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

### Context

I want to setup a docker enviroment for my new development right from the start.

This is the initial folder structure:

```
/development
├── dockerfiles
│   ├── backend
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── frontend
│   │   └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Currently I'm only trying to make the backend service to run.

After running each service for the first time I would like to have the following structure:

```
/development
├── backend # new folder
├── frontend # new folder
├── dockerfiles
└── docker-compose.yml
```

My train of thoughts is that, when first running the service, it should create a backend folder, do an installation of a NestJS and subsequents runs should only run the server.

To install NestJS I need to:
`RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli`

And to create a new project I need to:
`nest new <project name>`

I have several problems such as:

- the `nest new <project name>` command is interactive, meaning it asks for user input to configure the project.
- when creating the project, it creates a folder, meaning that if I want to have the `backend` folder at the root of the project, I need to bind mount the container to the whole project.

I want to use bind mounts because I will be constantly updating the code and I would like to have hot-refresh and all that good stuff.

Sinced based on wether the project is already created or not that some commands would run or not, I thought running command like `RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli` directly into the Dockerfile would not be a good idea so I thought of having a shell script to help me with that so I created a `init.sh` file.

```
/development
├── dockerfiles
│   └── backend
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       └── init.sh
└── docker-compose.yml
```

and then the Dockefile is looking like this:

```
FROM node:18.12.0

WORKDIR /app

RUN chmod +x /app/dockerfiles/backend/init.sh

CMD ["bash /app/dockerfiles/backend/init.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT [ "bash" ]
```

and the docker-compose.yml like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles/backend
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

Then I run the service with this command:
`docker-compose  run --build -p 3000:3000 backend`

but I got an error saying that the `init.sh` file cannot be found.

### Question

After all that, I want to find and execute the `init.sh` to help me deciding to install dependencies, only run the server, future implementations such as doing `git pull`, etc.

And this goes hand to hand with the bind mount, all the tutorials use `COPY` to copy a shell script into the container and the run it, but since Im using a bind mount, do I need the `COPY`? why is that it cannot find the `init.sh`?

Is it okay to have the bind mount to the full project even though the only relevant folder for that service is `backend`?

Is it another way to have this root-level folder containing directly the source code instead of having it nested into more folders?

I would really really appreciate any tips on the matter since I am used to dockerize existing code, but I don't know the proper process to dockerize an app from scratch.

Comment: Is `init.sh` already part of the image or do you have to copy it into the image first?

Comment: Currently, I'm not copying anything, since when I copied the file with COPY, when trying to run it, an error ocurred saying it could not find that file and for a fact, when doing ls to list the files inside the container, no init.sh was there. My guess is that it has something to do with the bind mount

Comment: This seems rather complicated a setup just to start a project.  Can you install Node directly on your system and install the Nest CLI the way you describe here, and delete all of the artifacts you've included in the question?

Comment: Thank you. Of course I could but the whole purpose of doing it this way is to isolate enviroments, I would like to set my system free of dev programs to avoid contaminating the PATH, slowing my pc performance, etc when I'm not developing anything